# Can I do Contract.Ensures on IQueryable and IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, iqueryable, code-contracts

Lets see this code:

```
public IQueryable<Category> GetAllActive()
{
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IQueryable<Category>>() != null);
    return dataSource.GetCategories(T => T.IsActive);
}
```

There is a small question. Is it okay with code contracts write this:

```
public IQueryable<Category> GetAllActive()
{
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IQueryable<Category>>() != null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IQueryable<Category>>().All(T => T.IsActive));
    return dataSource.GetCategories(T => T.IsActive);
}
```

Or not?

Will such a thing produce the unnecessary sequence enumeration, which is highly undesireble?

Comment: If you're using the full runtime contract checker, I fail to see how it can avoid forcing enumeration to occur - how else could it check it?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It couldn't. And I am not using runtime checker. For me, right now, the contracts is a way let the tools to test my code for simple possible logic conflicts.

Comment: So you need to clarify which parts of the contracts system you're using, if you want a clear answer. There are lots of options that can be turned on.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I use only the static checker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the binary rewriter and enforcing contracts at runtime, you should *not* do this.

When you use [`Contract.Ensures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.ensures.aspx) like so:

```
Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<T>() <operation>);
return expression;
```

It's transformed and the operation is lifted into something like the following:

```
T expression = <expression>;

// Perform checks on expression.
if (!(expression <operation>) <throw appropriate exception>;

// Return value.
return expression;
```

In this case, it means that your code unwinds to:

```
IQueryable<Category> temp = dataSource.GetCategories(T => T.IsActive);

// Perform checks.
if (!(temp != null)) throw new Exception();
if (!temp.All(T => T.IsActive)) throw new Exception();

// Return values.
return temp;
```

In this case, your [`IQueryable<Category>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) will be iterated through and will cause *another* request to be sent to the underlying data store.

Depending on the operation, you might not notice it, but the query is *definitely* going to be executed twice and that's bad for performance.

For things of this nature, you should check at the point of consumption of the `IQueryable<T>` whether or not you have any elements (you can do it with a boolean flag that is set as you `foreach` through it, or when you materialize it).

However, if you are *not* running the binary rewriter on your compiled assemblies, then [`Contract.Result<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412873.aspx) contracts of this nature cannot be enforced; in this case, it's a noop and probably shouldn't be there, as it's not doing anything.